# How to add extra USB port to Arduino Nano?

Tags: arduino-nano, usb, keyboard

I'm trying to use V-USB library to emulate a keyboard using Arduino Nano but because of precaution, I don't want to use it's built-in USB port.

My idea is to add another USB port so I cant power my device with the new USB port and use free digital pins as input/output of the new USB serial port in V-USB project.

What circuit I should use and how to add extra USB port to Arduino Nano.

Comment: By far the easiest way would be to buy a second Nano and connect the two together.

Comment: @Andrew of course it's easiest way but I care about the cost of the project!

Comment: The circuit diagram for connecting V-USB http://read.pudn.com/downloads194/sourcecode/embed/911688/vusb-20090822/circuits/with-zener.png

Answer (score 4):

[USB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB) is deceptively simple.  The underlying protocol is very complex. So a complete answer to your question requires some USB background.

USB is divided into 2 types.  USB Hosts and USB Devices. We are not concerned about USB Hosts here.  [USB Devices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Device_classes) only need to know about their own functions / features.  If they are a serial port device, like the FTDI chip on the Arduino Nano, they only need to "speak" basic USB protocol and the [serial CDC USB protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_communications_device_class).  If the USB Device was a keyboard, it only needs to know the basic USB protocol and the [HID USB protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_human_interface_device_class).

In order to offer up a USB port the Arduino Nano uses an [FTDI chip FT232RL](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/ICs/DS_FT232R.pdf).  This chip supports a Serial Port USB Device.  It does not appear to support HID USB Devices.  So your decision to use [V-USB](https://www.obdev.at/products/vusb/index.html) is necessary not because of power but because the Arduino Nano's built in USB port supports a protocol other than USB CDC.

> What circuit I should use and how to add extra USB port to Arduino
>   Nano.

The circuit suggested is on the [V-USB web page](https://www.obdev.at/products/vusb/index.html) appears to contain the necessary information:

[image]

Of course you will have to do some research into V-USB software to see which are the appropriate pins to use on your Arduino Nano.

Comment: The OP wants to use V-USB!

Comment: I see what you mean.  I'll edit my answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Since Arduino Nano have internal oscillator, can I setup only left side of the circuit?

Comment: My understanding is that USB is very picky about frequency.  Perhaps this is the reason that the V-USB web page included the external crystal.  However, the V-USB web page does say: "Can be clocked with 12 MHz, 15 MHz, 16 MHz 18 MHz or 20 MHz crystal or from a 12.8 MHz or 16.5 MHz internal RC oscillator.".

Answer (score 1):

You can use a USB host mini module for the Arduino NANO and the USB Host Library r2.0
[image]

You can implement a keyboard with this...